# Xerox postscript printer to use in software development

Tags: delphi, printing, postscript

months ago I was digging the web for a postscript driver and I met a xerox postscript driver that was at that time royalty free. I was needing it to develop a module in Delphi that printing from an external program would then use the ps generated from it to perform some other conversions.

The problem is that today, that I have the time to work on this project, I'm no more able to find that driver.

Someone knows where I can find it?

Answer (score 2):

*Any* PostScript driver should work. Install a printer with the driver, and then configure the printer to "print to file." You'll be prompted for a file name, and the output will be PostScript. The physical printer doesn't need to exist; choose the driver that supports the fanciest features you want from the drivers that come with your operating system.